# JavaScript Click EventHandler Reloading Page

Tags: javascript, uwp, eventhandler

I have a UWP app written in JS. I have added an eventhandler to a button for the click event. This triggers a function that starts an authentication process using a WebAuthenticationBroker in UWP.

```
if (document.getElementById('aadStartAuthButton')) { 
    document.getElementById('aadStartAuthButton').addEventListener('click', aadStartAuth, false); 
}
```

The button click handler works fine and when I press the button, it triggers the function, however, something else also happens. The WinJS log shows that a HTML1300 Navigation Occured event also happens. The page in the background appears to refresh which causes it to break out of the function and never complete it's task.

Surely a click event handler should not trigger a page refresh? Am I doing something wrong here?

I know that something isn't right because in the app, one of the first things I do is set a var. `authInProgress = false;` and the function that is called sets this to `authInProgress = true;` so that I can track the progress. If I attach a breakpoint somewhere near the top of the code, I can see that authInProgress is reverted to false.

Comment: What is your `#aadStartAuthButton` element? `<a>`, `<button>` or something else? Does it have a href? Try event.preventDefault();

Comment: Is element `#aadStartAuthButton` under any `<form>` tag ?

Comment: Wow, don't I feel like an idiot. I had been making some visual changes to the page using Bootstrap and I had wrapped the <button> element inside a <form< element. The default action of the form is applying to it and that's what is causing the refresh.

You @Sirence have not only saved me but also made me look like a fool publicly. Thanks!

Comment: @richardjgreen you don't look like a fool, everyone makes silly mistakes now and then.